# How to require / import chartist-plugin-tooltip in react app

Tags: reactjs, chartist.js

I'm using react-chartist in my project, and I would like to use the chartist-plugin-tooltip.
I saw in the documentation that I can add the plugin to an array of plugins under the chart options object.

The thing that I don't understand is how to import it or require it.
I've tried:

```
const tooltip = require('chartist-plugin-tooltip');
```

and

```
import { Chartist } from 'chartist-plugin-tooltip';
```

None of them work, when I try to assign to the plugins array:

```
plugins:[ Chartist.plugins.tooltip() ]
```

Has anyone made this working with react?

Comment: I managed to overcome the lack of documentation by requiring the plugin directly: `const tooltip = require('chartist-plugin-tooltip');` and in the plugins array I called it like this: `plugins:[ tooltip()]`

Comment: why dont you answer your own question? its legal :-)

Comment: Didn’t think about it...;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to overcome the lack of documentation by requiring the plugin directly:

```
const tooltip = require('chartist-plugin-tooltip');
```

and in the plugins array I called it like this:

```
plugins:[ tooltip()]
```

Comment: How to use it with `import`?

Comment: Could you share where this plugins array is?

Comment: Nevermind its probably in the options prop. But another issue im running into... says jquery is not found.